# How to create bitmaps quicker in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application where I am getting my data which includes images stored as blobs from a database, and then once I get this data in my application, I am transforming all of these into bitmaps, and storing the data in ArrayList for later use. When doing this for two dozen images it takes around 8 seconds; how can I create the bitmaps quicker. The images vary in height. In a for loop I am turning the image string into a byte array and then using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray. I am also using options.inSampleSize = 4.

Comment: If you're decoding a lot of images in a row like that, you probably need to find a new way to do things.  That's going to take a ton of memory and lead to OOM issues.  Especially if you're "storing in an ArrayList for later use".  If you aren't using them now or in the next few seconds, you shouldn't be loading them.

Comment: I am populating a list with these items, so I need to load all of them at that time. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Lazy loading.  Save the info needed to load the item at a later time, and load it only when needed.  Bitmaps are big.  They take 4*width*height bytes in memory.  Keeping several small ones isn't a big deal, but keeping all of them is trouble.  Lazy loading will save you a lot of OOM error later, and fix your perf errors (since you'll spread the loading out and do it only when needed).  Preferably combine with a cache (an LRU cache can have a max size put on it, so you won't use more than a predefined max amount of memory on images).

Answer (score 0):

Read images from database and store into local cache memory and then you read images from cache memory,it's efficient way of displaying bitmap.

Refer this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: As soon as I create the bitmap I am adding them to a view. The issue is the time it takes to create each bitmap.